# Do you use components when casting spells if you are a divine caster?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, divine

Does a divine caster need to use components when casting non-divine spells? 
For example does a druid casting [Flare](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/flare.htm) need to use the verbal casting component?

Citations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is *flare* really the example you're interested in? It has only a verbal component. Also, why do you think that *flare* isn't a divine spell?

Comment: Is it a divine spell? I was told that it was not, either way the important part here is if they would have to use the component for it. This happened in a game so would also like for that reason. 
Furhtermore i said components before you changed it so it would apply to more spells.

Comment: Just to check, is the premise of the question that a divine caster casting a divine spell *doesn't* need components?

Comment: That would be usefull to know aswell but the question here is: Do you use components when casting spells if you are a divine caster?

Answer (score 8):

A spell is arcane or divine according to which spell list it is on. Flare is on the Druid spell list, so *for* a Druid it is divine. (It's also on the Sorcerer spell list, so *for* a Sorcerer it's arcane.)

All spells normally require the listed components in order to cast, regardless of whether it is arcane or divine.

The evidence is that the [description of spell components](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#components) is part of the general "how spells work" section of the *PHB* (and SRD), so it applies to all spells unless otherwise noted. The later [section on divine magic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/divineSpells.htm) does not grant an exception, so they require the listed spell components.

Comment: Is there any Citations? Stubborn opponent on this one

Comment: @Simon Cites added!

Comment: Thanks! Seems that you are online and active, quick question: Nothing supports this but Wolf dosent advance to Dire Wolf, right? Animal companion.

Comment: @Simon I just happened to be here at the moment. :) If you have a new question, we do require it to be [asked as a new question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) so that everyone has a chance to answer and vote on the answers.

Comment: The only way I can see this confusion developing is out of this: "If the Components line includes F/DF or M/DF, the arcane version of the spell has a focus component or a material component (the abbreviation before the slash) and the divine version has a divine focus component (the abbreviation after the slash)." So, for example, a divine [*identify*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/identify.htm) doesn't need the arcane material component.